# Reload route does not refresh the api calls

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to build a functionality in Angular 7 where I click on a refresh button and that reloads the route ( not reload the page ) and refreshes the data ( I believe this will mean to make all api calls again).

The refresh click is implemented in a common component and its being used at all places in the application. In the constructor of the common component I have used :

```
this.someVariable = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.urlToRefresh = event.urlAfterRedirects;
  }
});
```

and then on click of refresh I am calling this.router.navigateByUrl(this.urlToRefresh);

This does seem to reload the route but it is not reloading the apis so the data is not refreshing. Is anything wrong or is there any other method to achieve this without a page refresh.

Comment: There isn't enough information here for anyone to help you effectively. We need to see the code thats handling the getting of data. However, I would suggest looking into 'LifeCycle hooks' here: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have 2 functions in which each function you are making api calls. Let assume both functions name `functionOneApi()` and `functionTwoApi()`.

And make a separate function in which you have to just calling both functions again means calling api again.

```
functionCalls(){
   functionOneApi();
   functionTwoApi()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Fahad but I think window.location.reload(); will do a page reload. I dont want to reload the page, just looking at refreshing the page with fresh data. Is that not possible by reloading the route?

Comment: so does that mean this.router.navigateByUrl("some_URL) does not make api calls to refresh the data?

Answer (score -1):

Theres a property in the `Router` that will cause the route to reload.

In your main routing module: (usually **app-routing.module.ts** or inside **app.module.ts**)

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' }
    )
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

You have to set the option `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'`. This will cause the route to reload when you navigate to the same route.

https://angular.io/api/router/Router#onSameUrlNavigation

> How to handle a navigation request to the current URL. One of:
>
> - 'ignore' : The router ignores the request.
> - 'reload' : The router reloads the URL. Use to implement a "refresh" feature.